# Merge lines which are not in proper

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk

I have the lines similar to below.

```
[1] 07:37:38 [bb..], qw, Exited with errojjjvice not known
[2] 07:37:39 [bfb.], fg, , This is FILE1, Stderrle or directory
[3] 07:37:39 [SU..], b b, ,, Stderr: bash: /sauch file or directory
cat: /root/file1: No, such, file or directory
[4] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], gh, , This is F :, No, such file or directory
[5] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], jk, ,, Stderr: bash: , No, such file or directory
nnnnnn, oot/file1: No, such, file or directory
hylll;; ooppgggh
[6] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], jjj, ,, Stderr: bash:  No, such file or directory
cat: /root/file1: No, such, file or directory
```

Need to append the line to their original cmd output line followed by comma.
And should start with square bracket containing numbers as below

```
[1] 07:37:38 [bb..], qw, Exited with errojjjvice not known
[2] 07:37:39 [bfb.], fg, , This is FILE1, Stderrle or directory
[3] 07:37:39 [SU..], b b, ,, Stderr: bash: /sauch file or directory, cat: /root/file1: No, such, file or directory
[4] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], gh, , This is F :, No, such file or directory
[5] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], jk, ,, Stderr: bash: , No, such file or directory, nnnnnn, oot/file1: No, such, file or directory, hylll;; ooppgggh
[6] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], jjj, ,, Stderr: bash:  No, such file or directory, cat: /root/file1: No, such, file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Your edit](https://superuser.com/revisions/1418063/2) made the question worse: the same fragment was repeated three times; it was not clear what you're asking. Probably a mistake while editing, therefore I did a rollback to the first version. Please edit again if you want to.

Comment: There was an edit attempt from *another* account, as if the original poster wanted to place an answer into the question. If it was you then please follow these two links: (1) [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) (2) [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If well understand, you want to join lines that doesn't begin wit square bracket.

Here is a perl way:

```
perl -0777 -i -ape 's/\R(?=[^[])/, /g' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?=         # positive lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we have after:
    [^[]    # any character that is not an opening square bracket
)           # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
,           # a comma followed by a space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
[1] 07:37:38 [bb..], qw, Exited with errojjjvice not known
[2] 07:37:39 [bfb.], fg, , This is FILE1, Stderrle or directory
[3] 07:37:39 [SU..], b b, ,, Stderr: bash: /sauch file or directory, cat: /root/file1: No, such, file or directory
[4] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], gh, , This is F :, No, such file or directory
[5] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], jk, ,, Stderr: bash: , No, such file or directory, nnnnnn, oot/file1: No, such, file or directory, hylll;; ooppgggh
[6] 07:37:39 [SUCCESS], jjj, ,, Stderr: bash:  No, such file or directory, cat: /root/file1: No, such, file or directory
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Yes, you're right I missread the question tags.